# RxJs: How to return result in finalize

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to return a result in `finalize`. Here's my code:

```
  const source = of(...packets);
  return source.pipe(
    concatMap(val =>
      writePacket(peripheralId, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID, val),
    ),
    map(res => {
      debugLog('in map ******');
      return {type: ResponseType.writeComplete};
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      debugLog('in finalize');
      return {type: ResponseType.writeComplete};
    }),

    catchError(err => {
      debugLog('in catch error', err);
      throwError(err);
    }),
  );
```

The result is returning in `map`, however, not in finalize. How do I get the result from finalize?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to return something from finalize? This operator is called when observable completes or terminates, so it's the last point where you can do something with your stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `finalize`'s callback is called during the *teardown phase*, e.g when the subscriptions are being unsubscribed. This may happen as a result of `complete`/`error` notifications. The callback's return value won't be taken into account.

What you can to instead is to use the `endWith` operator. So you could replace `finalize` like this:

```js
/* ... */
endWith({type: ResponseType.writeComplete})
/* ... */
```

As we can see from [its implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c746fec4ec8a1e8238ac79290ed3c9113996226f/src/internal/operators/endWith.ts)

```js
export function endWith<T>(...values: Array<T | SchedulerLike>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => concat(source, of(...values)) as Observable<T>;
}
```

`endWith` can take in multiple arguments,